# e-VISA to Georgia for UAE visa holder

Tags: visas, dubai, uae

I am a Bangladeshi passport holder with an Iraqi work permit, residing in Iraq. I am about to go on vacation in UAE for a couple of days. I was wondering if I can also spend a couple days in Georgia as well.

In the Georgia [e-visa portal](https://www.evisa.gov.ge/GeoVisa/en/VisaApp), when I mention that I have a UAE (single entry tourist) visa, the portal says apparently I'm visa exempt.

[image: visa exemption]

Is the exemption applicable for UAE residence only? Or is it also applicable for a UAE tourist visa holders? Can anyone confirm?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. Note, however, that if your UAE tourist visa is limited to one entry, and you enter the UAE before you go to Georgia, then when you later get to Georgia you will not at that moment be holding a valid UAE visa, as the UAE visa will have been "used up" by the previous UAE entry.

Comment: Noted. What about if I fly to Georgia first, and then UAE?

Comment: I have no first-hand experience with the UAE. From a logical perspective, however, previous use of a UAE visa to achieve entry into another country (here, Georgia) shouldn't affect the visa's continuing validity for entry into the UAE. (Just now saw the comment to Nicolas Formichella's answer, indicating that the Georgia visa exemption is not available to holders of an e-visa.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OP has an e-visa, they will need a visa

---

With a non-electronic visa, you can, but only in the Georgia → UAE routing

The reasoning is that your visa becomes invalid as soon as you've used your number of entries on your visa

TIMATIC states :

> Passengers with a visa issued by an EEA Member State , Bahrain, Bermuda, Canada, Cayman Isl., Falkland Isl. (Malvinas), Gibraltar, Israel, Japan, Korea (Rep.), Kuwait, New Zealand, Oman, Qatar, Saudi Arabia, Switzerland, Turks and Caicos Isl., USA, United Arab Emirates or Virgin Isl. (British) for a maximum stay of 90 days. This does not apply to passengers with an e-visa.

Comment: According to Emirate's  TIMATIC database...

"Visa Exemptions:
Passengers with a visa issued by an EEA Member State , Bahrain, Bermuda, Canada, Cayman Isl., Falkland Isl. (Malvinas), Gibraltar, Israel, Japan, Korea (Rep.), Kuwait, New Zealand, Oman, Qatar, Saudi Arabia, Switzerland, Turks and Caicos Isl., USA, United Arab Emirates or Virgin Isl. (British) for a maximum stay of 90 days. **This does not apply to passengers with an e-visa.**"

Since I have a UAE e-visa... I guess I'm out of luck?

Comment: @musavvir Yes, Timatic's wording indicates that the exemption does not apply to holders of a UAE e-visa.